# routing to a view without passing variables - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel.
In the question.blade view I receive two variables from a controller as follows :

1. @foreach ($answer as $answers)
2. #### {{$post->body}}

Sometimes I want to be routed to this question.blade view but without passing one or both of the variables. 
I noticed if I want for example to normally be linked to this view to view its contents , I receive this error :

Undefined variable: answer (View: D:\wamp\www\xxxxxxx\resources\views\Question.blade.php)

Is there a way to tell a blade to only expect variables when the user is routed by a specific controller=>method, while not expect variables when the user is routed by another method?

I hope this is clear :)

Comment: Why don't you just check if specified variable does exist?

Comment: can you give me a very simple example code, and where to do this check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to just check if desired variable does exist:

```
@if (isset($answers))
    @foreach ($answers as $answer)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endif

{{ isset($post) ? $post->body : '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the part of the view which have variable data , you may separate it as a partial blade view file . then you check if it is exists. or count the array .

```
@if(count($array))
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin: auto;">
        @include('partials.myview')
    </div>
@endif
```

Better to give the variable or array empty value to avoid errors for whatever reason .